# Windows Server 2008 with large pagefile.sys

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, pagefile

I found out that on our server with Windows Server 2008, we have a `pagefile.sys` of 62 GB. The current usage of the RAM is about 16GB of 32GB.

How can I find out which process caused this large file? We are risking running out of disk space on the system drive and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What happens when you restart the server?

Comment: @music2myear I try to avoid that. It is an important system.

Comment: You're running an OS that is going out of support in a few months now. If it is an important system you should be working to move it off of Server 2008. That said, if rebooting frees up the space, that is one piece of information, and the time it takes for the page file to grow again is another piece of information that may help diagnose the issue you're experiencing. Other things that may help would be to observe the Event Viewer or watch disk writes.

Comment: Isn't there a more direct way of finding out? For RAM, one can see which process takes which amount.  Is this possible for the pagefile as well?

Comment: All solutions are based on information gathered matched with knowledge attained or accessed. In the absence of someone with a good specific answer, you need to collect the information. One aspect of your question that could be improved would be for you to tell us what research you've done on this subject and what you have tried? If there were a commonly known way to resolve this, a web search would likely have revealed this to you.